# How to sort a file of strings using "sort" base on the last integer?

Tags: linux, sorting, ubuntu, unix, terminal

file = 
"hi wt" "you go" 5

"Ye s" "No N' 1

"a s" "k j" 2

"A" "B" 3

I want the answer like:

"hi wt" "you go" 5

"A" "B" 3

"a s" "k j" 2

"Ye s" "No N' 1

Answer (score 3):

Your question is answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10528):

```
awk '{print $NF,$0}' file.txt | sort -nr | cut -f2- -d' '
```

Andrea